# How to extrapolate time (as hour) per each recording (.wav file) identified in BirdNET?

Tags: r, birdsong, birdnet, data-processing, acoustic-monitoring

I deployed some passive acoustic devices to record bird song, and I am using birdNET for the first time. I downloaded the Windows version of the app, set the parameters I preferred and, after running a .wav file, this is what I get:

[image]

Is there any way to automatically reference each frame to start time of the file in excel or R instead of getting the start and end of each frame in seconds?
I am using GUI, with the following settings: minimum conf: 0.5, Sensitivity : 1, Overlap: 0., species by location. Latitude: 43, Longitude: -110, Week: 24

Thank you!

Comment: extrapolate with respect to which time? I guess you mean to reference each frame to start time of the file, which would not call extrapolate. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @WMXZ, I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Could you please add, how you invoke Birdnet (CLI or GUI) and if CLI which parameter and for GUI which parameter settigs?

Comment: Thanks, question edited again with these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you wanted to do that "automatically" you could just use your favourite programming language or even Excel.
In R, using the *lubridate* package, you would set the start `Date_Time` of the recording as a `ymd_hms` object like
`floor_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(name_of_your_file)`

set the start and end time as lubridate-time objects alike.

`datetime_start = lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(date, time_start)`

the you can just add them to your `start_date_time` with a +.
`datetime_start = (floor_time + datetime_start)`

hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, that was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to *"...automatically reference each frame to start time of the file..."* you have to know the start time of that file (well, duh!).  Fortunately, sound files commonly include that information as part of their filename.

For example, I was recently asked to analyze a sound file with the following filename:

SWIFT #2_96K_**20200621_172433**.wav

Note the bolded portion, which contains the **date_time** that the recording started.  This recording started on June 21, 2020 at 24 minutes and 33 seconds after 5 pm.  The field recorder automatically appended that information to the filename as **yyyymmdd_hhmmss**, where:

**yyyy** = year
**mm** = month
**dd** = day
**hh** = hour (24)
**mm** = minute
**ss** = second

If this file contained a sound that had a start time of 14 seconds, then that time is simply added to the filename's **date_time**.  In this case that sound would have started on June 21, 2020 at 24 minutes and 47 seconds after 5 pm.

AFAIK, most field recorders automatically include the starting **date_time** as part of the filename.  If your sound files do not include this, then you'll need to locate some metadata that includes the recording's start time.  Failing that, I don't know how you would be able to determine a start time...